# Is there a model that combines the difference-in-difference and MIDAS together?

Tags: r, difference-in-difference, midas

Is there a difference-in-difference (DiD) regression model that also works with mixed data frequencies (MIDAS)?

In other words, is there a model that combines the difference-in-difference and MIDAS together?

If so, may I please know any R code or package that can work with this?

Comment: Perhaps a little explanation of what you mean by "mixed data frequencies" would be helpful.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica: It means you want to run a regression using regressors with different frequencies. Some regressor might have daily frequency, others might have quarterly or yearly frequencies and so on.